# axios requests start right away not waiting for the axios.all

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

My axios promise does not work as expected. I guess the execution starts inside the `forEach` loop. I want the axios execution to start only after the `batch.commit`

```
aMobileNumbers.forEach(function(iMobileNumber) {
    promises.push(axios.post('https://example.com', {
            'app_id' : "XXXXXXX-7595",
            'contents' : { "en":`${sText}` },
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
        .catch((response) => console.log(response))
    );
})

console.log(`#${context.params.pushId} Promises: `, promises);

return batch.commit().then(() => {
    console.log(`wrote`);
    return axios.all(promises); //<--- doesnot execute here
})
.then(() => db.doc(`/MGAS/${context.params.pushId}`).delete())
.then(() => console.log(`Deleted the MQ`))
.catch((error) => console.log(`#${context.params.pushId} ${error}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling axios `post` method will indeed start the request. If you want to start the requests after the commit, you should place your code inside the `then` callback:

```
return batch.commit().then(() => {
    console.log(`wrote`);

    var promises = aMobileNumbers.map(function(iMobileNumber) {
        return axios.post('https://example.com', { // <--- does execute here
                'app_id' : "XXXXXXX-7595",
                'contents' : { "en":`${sText}` },
            })
            .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
            .catch((response) => console.log(response));
    })

    console.log(`#${context.params.pushId} Promises: `, promises);

    return axios.all(promises);
})
.then(() => db.doc(`/MGAS/${context.params.pushId}`).delete())
.then(() => console.log(`Deleted the MQ`))
.catch((error) => console.log(`#${context.params.pushId} ${error}`));
```

Comment: I do not specifically want the request to be called after the `commit` but I just want to know will the function waits till all the axios request complete ?

Comment: In both the original code and the code in the answer, all the requests will be completed before calling the delete method.
The difference is that in the question code the ajax requests will start immediately and in the answer code the ajax requests will start after the batch commit.

Comment: @AH. Then why did you ask "*I want the axios execution to start only after the `batch.commit`*"?

Comment: Btw, I would recommend to use `map` instead of `forEach` here.

Comment: Edited the code to introduce `map` instead of `forEach`. I did not change it initially so that the answer code resembled the original question code.

Comment: What's the advantage of `map` over `forEach` ?

Comment: Take a look at [map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

You are transforming an array of items into an array of promises.